# How to stop a nonce from being cached in an inline script, or alternatives to regenerate it if expired?

Tags: ajax, security, nonce

I have an inline script that gets added into some WordPress pages which fires an AJAX request. We pass a nonce in that script, when using full page caching that nonce might have expired and therefore the AJAX request can't validate it.

1. Is there a way to stop the nonce being cached? (guessing not as its just static page code?)
2. Is there a way around this, e.g. if the nonce check fails in `example_action` function, can I safely pass back a newly generated nonce from the AJAX response, refire `ajaxTest()` with the new nonce generated? If feasible are there any security concerns of doing this?

**Example inline script:**

```
<script>
    jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {

        function ajaxTest() {

            var ajaxRequestData = {
                'action': 'example_action',
                'nonce': '<?php echo esc_html( wp_create_nonce( 'example_nonce' ) ); ?>', // This could have expired when using full page caching
            };
                                                
            var ajaxRequest = jQuery.ajax({
                'url':      '<?php echo esc_html( admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ); ?>',
                'method':   'POST',
                'data':     ajaxRequestData,
            });
            
            ajaxRequest.done( function( response ) {
            
                alert( response ); // Shows is nonce valid/invalid
            
            });

        }

        ajaxTest();

    });
</script>
```

**Example function that returns the response**

```
function example_action() {

    $nonce_status = 'invalid';

    if ( isset( $_POST['nonce'] ) ) {

        if ( wp_verify_nonce( sanitize_key( $_POST['nonce'] ), 'example_nonce' ) ) {

            $nonce_status = 'valid';

        }

    }

    echo $nonce_status;

    wp_die();

}
```